# Finding the domain and form of a composition of functions

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm trying to find the domain and the form of the composition of the following functions:
$f:y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ , $g:y=1-x^2$.

My solution is the following:
domain = $[-1,1]$
, form = $f\circ g: y= 1-x^3$

My steps:

domain: $D(f\circ g)=${$x\in\mathbb{R}, 1-x^2\in\mathbb{R}^+$},   $\Rightarrow 1-x^2\geq 0$ $\Leftrightarrow x^2\leq 1$ $\Rightarrow x\in[-1,1]$

form: $1-(\sqrt{x^3})^2 \Leftrightarrow 1-x^3$

Is it correct? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you end up with those?

Comment: I think, you should get $\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}$.

Comment: And the domain is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Gae.S. hmm.. I will edit the post with my steps.

Comment: @HVxvejjw Updated the post with my steps, could you please tell me where I did a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

To find the domain of the composite function

$$( f \circ g )(x)=f(g(x))$$

one can follow these two steps

1. Find the domain of the inside (input) function.
2. Construct the composite function. Find the domain of this new function. If there are restrictions on this domain, add them to the restrictions from Step 1. If there is an overlap, use the more restrictive domain (or the intersection of the domains).

In your case, the domain of the inside function $g(x)=1-x^2$ is all real numbers while the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is also all real numbers.

The domain of the composite function is where $f(g(x))=f(1-x^2)=\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}$ is defined. Although, observe that $\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}$ is also defined for all real numbers.

Therefore, the domain of $f(g(x))$ is all real numbers.

Comment: I edited the post with my steps, could you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: I'd say the domain of $\sqrt[3]\bullet$ is not $[0,\infty)$, but $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I'm really confused right now. Is the cube root defined for negative numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ or not?

Comment: Ah! I made the same mistake you did! I shouldn't have trusted [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%281%2F3%29) result without drawing the function myself. The domain of the cube root of x is all real numbers.

Comment: I don't see a problem with $\sqrt[3]x:=\text{the one and only real number }u\text{ such that }[u^3=x]$, for $x<0$.

Comment: So, why did Wolfram Alpha return the wrong result? Is it a bug?

Comment: @Axion004 No, it's just that in many cases wolframalpha reads $z^\alpha:=\exp\left(\alpha\operatorname{Log }z\right)$, where $\operatorname{Log}$ is the principal value of the complex logarithm. For $\alpha=1/3$ it also warns you that it's using it and it asks if you wish to use the "real cube root".